# Jquery Undefined when running script in console

Tags: jquery, iframe, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have an issue with a piece of script I am running which is suppose to populate this modal:

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Latest Updates!</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
     </div>   
    </div>
```

The code is:

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){  
        $('a.updateNotes').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            $(".modal-body").html('<iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" allowtransparency="true" src="'+url+'"></iframe>');
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

The issue is that when I run that code in the console of chrome I get "undefined" yet there are no actual console errors on the code it's self. That is when the page loads the code throws no issues, but if I run it in the console I get "undefined" Can some one tell me what I am doing wrong? The link that creates this, is:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-success" href="http://adambalan.com/aisis/aisis_update/UpdateNotes/index.html" 
data-target="#modal">
    Learn More!
</a>
```

If you go to that actual link, you'll see content that I should see in the box. Also will the box expand to fit the content? that is expand to a specific width then scroll for anything longer?

**Jquery 1.9.latest, Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.1**

**Note:** the reason the Jquery is wrapped in `(function($){})(jQuery)` is because of WordPress and how it deals with Jquery, it doesn't like the $ because of other script's it uses.

**Upade** Jquery version 1.9.1 is being loaded in the header of the page. Clicking the link to the source takes me to the Jquery 1.9.1 source. While the code shown above is apart of the html file it's self, how ever it is "executed" **AFTER** the loading of jquery 1.9.1

Comment: thats because jquery really is `undefined`.. ul have to paste the entire jquery.js code before you start typing your own code if you want jquery to be in context in console

Comment: @passionateCoder: jQuery will run fine in the console if it's been loaded by the page first.  It's not clear in this example whether he's loaded it first, before the dom ready block.

Comment: Its never worked for me that way @MaxWilliams. . #Tested on Chrome 23

Comment: Please See Updated OP @passionateCoder

Answer (score 0):

View the source on your page throwing the `undefined` error and check the js load order.

The jquery core file is probably loading after your script.

Wordpress, particularly with plugin js code and maybe in your case, needs to know if there is a jquery dependency so it can load the jquery core file before the plugin js.

If you can't change the order in which the jquery core file loads in, move your js code down so jquery is available when your code is run.

Comment: Jquery version 1.9.1 is being loaded in the header of the page. Clicking the link to the source takes me to the Jquery 1.9.1 source. Please see updated OP

Comment: @TheWebs Do you have a full test page that we can see?